# I would like to group/split age values

Tags: r, rstudio-server

I have a dataset that has the cat's ID number at a centre and their ages. The dataset looks like this:

```
ID Number   Animal Type          Age
 121012             Cat        0.002
 128129             Cat        1.000
 429202             Cat        0.920
 238232             Cat       15.000
 132265             Cat        0.050
 234235             Cat        9.000
 682892             Cat       16.000
```

A kitten has an age numerical value below 1, in other words, kittens can be any number that isn't a whole number. 
Meanwhile, adult cats have an age value that is any whole number.

I need to split the data, or better yet group, the kitten population from the adult population but I have no idea.

(Im still pretty new to this, only had it for 4 weeks so sorry if I sound like a noob)

Many thanks to anyone who can help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the above answer, find below two more methods,

Method 1

```
df_kitten <- subset(df, Age <1)
df_adult <- subset(df, Age >= 1)
```

Method 2

```
df_kitten <- df[df$Age < 1,]
df_adult <- df[df$Age >= 1,]
```

Thanks
Balaji

Comment: The first method didn't work as well I wanted but the second method worked better.  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to split your data, you can use `dplyr::group_by` to ensure a grouping structure of your `data.frame`.

```
library(tidyverse);
df %>%
    mutate(isKitten = Age < 1) %>%
    group_by(isKitten)
```

Any further data manipulations will then be performed on the group level.

For example, you can calculate the mean age per group:

```
df %>%
    mutate(isKitten = Age < 1) %>%
    group_by(isKitten) %>%
    summarise(meanAge = mean(Age))
## A tibble: 2 x 2
#  isKitten meanAge
#  <lgl>      <dbl>
#1 FALSE     10.2
#2 TRUE       0.324
```

Comment: you can also directly use `group_by(isKitten = Age < 1)`

Comment: @Jimbou Great! I was not aware of this.

Answer (score 0):

```
df_split = split(df, df$Age < 1)
```

Or you might want to create a column that says if the cat is kitten or adult:

```
df$type_of_cat <- ifelse(df$age < 1, "Kitten", "Adult")
df_split = split(df, df$type_of_cat)
```

I am assuming your table only contains cats.